# How can I retrieve SMS messages from a telephone operator?

Tags: android

I can get the user's telephone operator using TelephonyManager, and I need to use this name to retrieve texts received from the operator. How can I use something like an SQL where clause with Android's ContextResolver.query() method? Here's my code to retrieve ALL the text messages received by the user. I need to tweak it to retrieve the messages from the user's telephone operator.

```
public void fetchSMS() {

    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String operator=tMgr.getNetworkOperatorName();
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    String[] cols = new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type"};
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
            mSmsinboxQueryUri,
            cols, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1!=null && cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(cols[2]));
            //String address2=(address.split("-"))[1];

                String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(cols[4]));
                String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(cols[5]));
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(cols[6]));

                smsLog.append("\n" + "Address:").append(address).append("\n" + "Date:").append(date).append("\n" + "Message:").append(msg).append("\n" + "Type:").append(type).append("\n\n");
            cursor1.moveToNext();
        }
        while (!cursor1.isAfterLast());
        cursor1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this - reliably, anyway - unless you know every address from which any given operator can send SMS. There is no column in the SMS table that holds the operator name, and there's no guarantee that a message from the operator will have its name in the message body.

Comment: When a sender receives a message from his/her telecom operator after a recharge(prepaid phones), they receive a text from a particular address(my phone operator is called Docomo, and the message I receive has the sender as TA-Docomo). Same for other operators. I just need to know how to add a where clause in the query() method.

Comment: Well, that's not guaranteed to be the case for everyone, but if you just want a simple where clause, your query would be something like: `query(mSmsinboxQueryUri, cols, "address LIKE '%" + operator + "%'", null, null)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

May be its useful for you.

[More Information refer this page](http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/).

**SmsBroadcastReceiver.java**

This is a BroadcastReceiver which receives the intent-filtered SMS messages. onReceive, we extract the SMS message bundle and show a toast message and also update the UI by adding the SMS message to the SMS inbox list. When a SMS message arrives, the inbox is automatically refreshed.

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //this will update the UI with message
            SmsActivity inst = SmsActivity.instance();
            inst.updateList(smsMessageStr);
        }
    }
}
```

**SmsActivity.java**
This is the main Android activity of the SMS application. It acts as the SMS inbox. It has a ListView to show the SMS messages. onCreate we read all the messages present in the internal SMS inbox from its Uri and show them using the ListView.

```
public class SmsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static SmsActivity inst;
    ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView smsListView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    public static SmsActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        refreshSmsInbox();
    }

    public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                    "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
        arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        try {
            String[] smsMessages = smsMessagesList.get(pos).split("\n");
            String address = smsMessages[0];
            String smsMessage = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; ++i) {
                smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
            }

            String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
            Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't exactly what I was looking for, but nonetheless, is something worth knowing. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer gives solution to you. Give upvote & accepted my answer. Thanks.@SubravetiSuraj